# What is the behaviour of $f(x) =\frac{1}{\sin(x)}$ and $f^{\prime}(x) =-\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)}$ as $|x|\to +\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry

As an exercise for my math class I have this one. Let
$$f(x) =\frac{1}{\sin(x)}, \qquad f^{\prime}(x) =-\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)}.$$
Find an estimate for $f$ and $f^{\prime}$ as $|x|\to +\infty$ (with the meaning of something like $|f(x)|\le a$ as $|x|\to +\infty$ or something like that).

I am in trouble with that since both function has in infinite set of singularities (it should be $x\neq k\pi$) and I don't know what means in this case $|x|\to +\infty$.
Could someone please help?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't think such bound exist, you confusion is well-founded.

Comment: Both $f$ and $f'$ are oscillatory, going from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. The only thing I can say is that they are periodic

Comment: $f$ is not defined on $\Bbb R$, say, for $x=\pi n, n=0, \pm 1,\pm 2,... $, so the question is meaningless.